# Implementing basic operations for built-in types without using libcore

Tags: rust, osdev

When I write a simple code for bare metal without using libcore I get the following error:

> error: binary operation `!=` cannot be applied to type `u32` [E0369]

Straight forward implementation confronts the chicken-and-egg problem:

```
#![crate_type = "lib"]
#![feature(no_std, no_core, lang_items)]
#![no_std]
#![no_core]

#[lang = "sized"]
pub trait Sized {}

#[lang = "sync"]
pub trait Sync {}

pub const CONST1: u32 = 1;
pub const CONST2: u32 = 2;

pub struct Struct {
    pub field: u32,
}

impl Sync for Struct {}

pub static VAR: Struct = Struct {
    field: CONST1 + CONST2,
};
```

Here I get the following error:

> error: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `u32` [E0369]

Comment: "*Actually I've solved my problem*" — you might as well add how you solved it as an answer; that's perfectly acceptable and encouraged behavior.

Comment: It's more precisely to say that I just found a workaround to the problem (just copied the corresponded libcore snippet), not solved it. So I cannot add an answer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your the error you describe on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7c9ce3e7575ffc7b76e2&version=nightly) (warning! much hacking to get it to compile!).  It compiles fine after addressing all the "missing lang item" errors.  Could you provide a link to a playpen demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually the expected behavior nowadays. Rust requires the "add" lang item to be implemented for the type, even if it is a built-in type. The implementation can be completely bogus (as long as it compiles), since it will be [replaced by the built-in operation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27824#issuecomment-133165027).

The reason this is done this way is that the code type-checking the built-in types was buggy and complex. Doing it this way simplified the type-checking code and the trait implementations were already there anyway.

Therefor you need to add the following two declarations to be able to use the `+` operator even on the built-in type `u32`

```
#[lang = "add"]
pub trait Add<RHS=Self> {
    type Output;
    fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;
}

impl Add for u32 {
    type Output = u32;
    fn add(self, _rhs: u32) -> u32 { 42 }
}
```

Here's a full example that doesn't link since it's missing some libc stuff: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a223d48b0f2d8533996f&version=nightly

Note that you should NOT create a bogus implementation as shown, because you might be using the built-in type in a generic context, where the implementation will actually be used